# How to let user download a image to Photos on click with React.js?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, mobile, download

What I want to achieve:

When the user clicks a button, the image should be saved to Photos.

What's the current behaviour:

On click, the user is sent to a new page that only that image exists.

```
<a href={imageUrl} target="_blank">button</a>
```

On click, the user is asked if they want to download the image. Upon accepting it, the image is saved in OneDrive instead of their Photos, which causes them not able to find it.

```js
export const downloadFile = (url: string, filename: string) => {
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        response.blob().then(blob => {
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            a.click();
            a.remove();
        });
    });
}
```

Is there a better way to let the user download the image directly to their Photos instead of either of the two actions above?

UPDATE:

Tried with the mime-type and content-disposition, still sent to File instead of Photos.

[image]

And when I open the link on iOS, it pop up a dialog like this:

[image]

When I click "View", it will open a page with the image shown.

When I click "Download", it will download to my iCloud Drive directly without letting me choose to save it in my Photos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called File-saver. Read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver). It has a `saveAs()` function which you can use like this:

```
FileSaver.saveAs("https://httpbin.org/image", "image.jpg");
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: DIdn't work, still sending it to File.

Answer (score 0):

If your back-end server defines image resource as `Content-Disposition` (rfc here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6266), you can just make browser to trigger image download with `window.location.assign("[image-url]")`.
Note that you have to response `Content-Type` header correctly based on image's format(.jpg, .png or others) on your back-end server implementation.

Comment: I just tried with the correct content type with `content-disposition` settled, but it still downloads to my OneDrive instead of Photos. Tried with jpg, and Content-Type is 'image/jpeg'.

Comment: Try not to include slash('/') in your `Content-Disposition` filename. And what is it to do with OneDrive? Users can choose where their images to save with a browser provided dialog.

Comment: In the provided dialog, they can only choose whether to "view" or "download" the file. If they choose "download", the file goes to OneDrive directly without letting them choose where to save it. And if they choose "view", the page with just that image opens.

Comment: Are you using linux or OSX? This file dialog maybe platform variant. I have tested my answer on windows edge, ios safari and android webview on my old project before(I used this on my project, too), everything works fine.

Comment: And many browsers have file download settings for their users to chose, users can choose to save file automatically without ask and define default download location. I think that's NOT what you should concern about.

Comment: Sorry, not One Drive. It is iCloud Drive. I have updated the dialog I see in the question. It is Safari btw, which should be the majority of my users would be using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254083/discussion-between-terry-windwalker-and-paper-folding).

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to download an image, maybe you can try this code

```
function onDownloadImage(src) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = () => {
    // create Canvas
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    // for create tag anchor
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = `image-download`;
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    a.click();
  };
}
```

after that you can call this function inside your component. for example:

```
return (
 <a href="#" onClick={() => onDownloadImage("url your image")}>Download Here ...</a>
)
```

Comment: Just to note, downloading is not the issue. The issue is I want to let my mobile users download the image into their Photos or Camera Roll rather than saving it in their storage like iCloud Drive. This code would download to their iCloud Drive for some reason.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).